# $.post in the following code does not work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The Function updateTtotal() is used for Autosum generation in Tables.

```
 function updateTtotal(element) {     
 var form = element.form;
 var num = element.name.replace(/^\D+/,'');
 var value = parseFloat(form['value' + num].value) + parseFloat(form['tax_amount' + num].value);
 form['total' + num].value =  (value == 0)? '0' : value;
updateGtotal(form);
 }
 function updateGtotal(form) {
 var elements = form.elements;
 var name = /^total/;
 var total = 0;
 var value;
var flag =0;
 for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
   if ((name.test(elements[i].name))&&(elements[i].value!=0)) {
    total += parseFloat(elements[i].value);
   }
 }
 form.g_total.value = total;
 var val = total;
 $.post( "numconv.php", { amount: val})// This Code generates no error but does not work
    .done(function( data ) {
            form.g_total_word.value = data;
    });
 }
```

The numconv.php is as given below.(this works fine while executed successfully)

```
<?php 
require_once("include/currency_class.php");
$var = new CurrencyToWords();
$amt = floatval($_POST['amount']);
$result = $var->translateInWords($amt);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Is done() callback called? Check your network tab, any error?

Comment: It seems there is no error. What do you think the problem. Also, I've executed a similar code yesterday. It works fine even now...

Comment: Looks like a serever side error. Add fail() callback to ajax request and check for error. See at least if fail() callback is reached. BTW, you didn't answer if the done() callback was called or not

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot. done() is not called...

Comment: Perhaps your POST url path is not correct.. 
Try adding fullpath: 
"/all dirs if there are Dirs/numconv.php" - you may skip only domain but it must starts with /

Comment: The fail() also fails to execute.

Comment: Providing the full path also didn't helped me guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing $post function to this - might help to see what's the problem:

```
$.post("numconv.php", {
amount: val
 })
.success(function(data){    
 //some code on data return if you want
  alert(data + " success function");
})
.done(function(data){
  alert(data + " done function");
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  alert("Unable to retrieve data from the server, error code:" + errorThrown);
});
```

hope it helps somehow.

Comment: This alternative also doesn't work. Any of the following methods(done(),success() or fail()) seems non responsive.

Comment: in that case, make sure you manage to call the post function (try placing an alert("going to post function"); ) just before post, and see if the alert pops up. If yes, make sure your numconv.php file is placed in the same folder where the current document file is placed, and whether is named like you call it, make sure you PHP server is working.. The function is definitely working, I am using this function for all of my ajax calls and it works perfectly.